# Stringstream weird behaviour

Tags: c++, iostream

I don't know if this is actually weird or this is how it's supposed to be, but here's my current struggle. Suppose we have something like:

```
stringstream sso("12 1442 nana 7676");
double num = 0;
while(sso >> num || !sso.eof()) {
    if(sso.fail()) {
        sso.clear();
        string dummy;
        sso >> dummy;
        continue;
    }
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

That results in:

```
12
1442
7676
```

as expected. But if I , for example, change the string literal into `12 + 1442 nana 7676`, then I get:

```
12
7676
```

Why does the character `'+'` mess things up here ?

Comment: Because `+` is a valid prefix for a positive number, but then it must be directly followed by a digit. If not things get out of sync for the next number as well I guess?

Comment: I don't think your original expectations were correct

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Makes sense, but I don't think it should work like that. Do you?

Comment: If you want the gritty details please read about [`std::num_get::do_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know now, `+` is a valid token for a `double`, so you need a way to skip *to* the next space-separated token instead of just getting rid of it. This function can do it for you:

```
template<class Ct>
std::basic_istream<Ct>& next_token(std::basic_istream<Ct>& is) {
  is.clear();
  std::ctype<Ct> const& ctype = std::use_facet<std::ctype<Ct>>(is.getloc());
  if (ctype.is(ctype.space, is.peek())) {
    return is >> std::ws;
  }
  Ct c;
  while (is.get(c) && !ctype.is(ctype.space, c)) {
    ;
  }
  return is;
}
```

Then you can change your code to:

```
stringstream sso("12 + 1442 nana 7676");
double num = 0;
while (sso) {
  if (!(sso >> num)) {
    sso >> next_token;
  } else {
    cout << num << endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
12
1442
7676
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution, but I'm struggling with the mechanics of operator >>. Is this really weird behaviour or this is how 'they' wanted to be ?

Comment: @domo This isn't weird at all. What you expected was for the plus character to not be skipped over, but the plus character is a valid token for a double so the stream extracted it and moved ahead to the next character. Since the next character (a space) isn't valid, it did nothing and stopped there. This is the way it's supposed to work. The stream extracts as many valid characters as possible until it finds one that is invalid for that type.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it . How come 1442 gets neglected then?